# Difference between modelValue and viewValue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

With a custom directive, a validation function is added to validate integer input

```
var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+$/;
app.directive('integer', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Each function in the $validators object receives the modelValue and the viewValue.

What is the difference between modelValue and viewValue ?

Comment: See the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewValue

Comment: @RahilWazir - That link is of little help with respect to the `$validators` signature.  I understand angular is a huge library, but function signatures should be required documentation.  Especially considering javascript's dynamic nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to define `$formatter`s and `$parser`s in your [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). The viewValue is the value that the rendering directive uses to draw itself, the modelValue is what is stored in the scope once ngModel's `$parser` list hase been applied. If you change the value in the scope, ngModel will run that value through its `$formatters` which is then read by the rendering directive as a viewValue.

Often the viewValue is the string that is displayed in an input element whereas the modelValue is the value that has been parsed into the target format (a Date object in a datepicker directive, for example)